# Why can't I set *this == class object

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, definition, assignment-operator

I was reviewing at the overload operator =.
Why i can set 'this == &st' but not '*this == st' ?

```
StringBad & StringBad::operator=(const StringBad & st)
{
    if (this == &st)           // if the object assigned to itself, return to itself. 
        return *this;          // why compiler give error when I set *this ==st ?

/* blah blah
...
... */

    return *this;              // return reference to invoking object
}
```

Comment: You can but you dont want to

Comment: Do you have a `StringBad::operator==`?  If not you can't use `==` with them.

Comment: Also, just because two objects compare equal doesn't mean they are the same object.

Comment: *why compiler give error when I set *this ==st ?* -- You should be glad it gave you that error.  If it didn't, you now would have a broken `operator=`.

Comment: Thanks guys. i get the idea. one more question then. what does the name of class object represents? like in array, name of array represents the first element of array.

Comment: "in array, name of array represents the first element of array" it does not, so your question is meaningless

Comment: you want to know if `this` == address of its first own field ? (supposing it has)

Comment: *name of array represents the 'address' of the first element

Comment: warning you cannot accept 2 answers if you think you can

Comment: lol yeah just realized that

Comment: if you like 2 answers (or more) you can accept one and up vote the other(s)

Comment: "name of array represents the 'address' of the first element" - No. An array can *decay* to a pointer to the first element, but the name of an array is not a pointer to the first element. There are cases where this difference matters.

Comment: Oh i see thanks bruno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two different objects can be equal each other but this does not mean that they are the same.

Consider for example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() 
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    std::cout << "x == y is " << std::boolalpha << ( x == y ) << '\n';
    std::cout << "&x == &y is " << std::boolalpha << ( &x == &y ) << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
x == y is true
&x == &y is false
```

So this check `this == &s` is required to determine whether here there is a self-assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Comparing 2 pointers is *not* the same thing as comparing the values at those pointers. e.g.

```
int *a, *b;
if(a == b) 
if (*a == *b) // not the same
```

Of course, if 2 pointers are the same, then they point to the same value, but the converse is not true.

In this case, checking if `*this == st` will compile (assuming `operator==` is defined for `StringBad`), but it's not the same thing as checking if `this == &st`.

Answer (score 0):

> Why i can set `this == &st` but not `*this == st` ?

I think you mean to say, Why i can use `this == &st` but not `*this == st` ?

Ignoring that for a minute, the answer is that, yes you can, but it's not necessarily the right thing to do always. It might be appropriate for your case. In that case, you should certainly use it. Of course, it implies that you need to implement `operator==` for your class first.

Here's an example where you should not use `*this == st` to make the assignment a noop.

Let's say you have a class that captures a physical quantity with a value and units and let's say you have:

object `a`, that represents 1 "m".
object `b`, that represents 100 "cm".

When yoou compare `a` with `b`, you should get back `true`. But when you assign `a` to `b` or vice versa, IMO you should proceed with the assignment.